# Menu bar is not appearing in menu button in mobile layout

Tags: html

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7qmM.png)To make my website responsive for mobile layout, I am trying to make the navigation menu appear on clicking the menu button. However, the click is not working and navigation options are not appearing at all. Only the navigation menu icon is appearing. The options are appearing below the menu button separately. However, I want them to appear on clicking the menu icon.

```css
.navbar {
   width: 100;
   text-align: center;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 35px;
   font-size: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
    
}
.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 color: #0069BD;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}
.navbar .current{
   border-bottom: 3px solid #0069BD;  /* Showing the border under the navigation option on hover */
} 
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 18px;   
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    margin: 0;
 
 color: #0069BD;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
     border-bottom: 3px solid  #00A0EF;
}
.navbar a {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0069BD;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1000;
 font-size: 10px;
  
}
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 font-size: 17px; 
 
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid  #00A0EF;
 color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.active {
    color: white;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}


.active {
    color: white;
}

.content  p{
 font-size: 13px;
  color: #4e5153;

 font-weight: normal;
 font-family: 'Arial' sans-serif;
 line-height: 20px;
 display:inline-block;
 
}
/* Header Logo */
header div.logo {
 padding-top: 14px;
 padding-right: 24px;
 float: left;
 border: red;
}

header div.logo a {
 width: 216px;
 height: 74px;
 float: left;
 text-indent: -999em;

}
div.page {
 min-height: 400px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html><!-- head --><head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile"> <!-- image displayed on the tab alongwith the title-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo.jpg"> <!-- image displayed on the tab alongwith the title-->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <!-- encoding scheme-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Marvel Tech</title>  <!--title of the tab-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!--icons used in footer-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <!--stylesheet Linking-->
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- javascript used for slider animation-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script> <!-- javascript used for slider animation-->
</head> 
    <!-- Body-->        
<body>
        <div class="page-wrap">
   <!--- Header section -->
<header>
  <div class="headercontent">
    <div class="logo">
  <img src="images/newlogo.jpg" style="height: auto;">
          </div>
    <!--–– Navigation Bar -->
<div class="navbar">
         <a class="current" href="Marvel_Tech.html">Home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Services 
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> <!--arrow displayed next to drop-down list-->
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="Services.html">Design</a>
    <a href="Services.html">Consulting</a>
    <a href="Services.html">R&amp;D</a>
  </div>
   </div> 
    <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Software
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> <!--arrow displayed next to drop-down list-->
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="Software.html">Steam Turbine Design Package</a>
    <a href="Software.html">Gas Turbine Design Tools</a>
    <a href="Software.html">Power Plant Monitoring</a>
    <a href="Software.html">Prognostic System</a>
  </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Products
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> <!--arrow displayed next to drop-down list-->
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="Products.html">ORC Turbine</a>
    <a href="Products.html">Gas Turbine</a>
    <a href="Products.html">Saturated Team Turbine</a>
  </div>
   </div> 
  <a href="About.html">About</a>
  <a href="Contact.html">Contact </a>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Language
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>  <!--arrow displayed next to drop-down list-->
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="Marvel_Tech.html"><img src="images/english.png" style="height: auto;"> English    </a>
       <a href="Marvel_Tech_Chinese.html"><img src="images/chinese.png" style="height: auto;"> Chinese  </a> <!--- Mention the name of chinese page in place of hash.-->
  </div>
   </div> 
</div>
  </div> 
 </header></div>
   
 

<div class="mobilenavbtn">
 <div class="content">
 <a href="#"><img src="images/mobilenavbtn.png" alt="Menu" style="height: auto;"></a>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Create HTML:

```
 <!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
```

Step 2) Create CSS:

```
 /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
 background-color: #333;
 overflow: hidden;
 }

   /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
   .topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: black;
 }

 /* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
 }

 /* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
 display: none;
  }
```

Comment: In addition go to  [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the original post to elaborate the problem. The menu is appearing fine in laptop layout. However, as evident from the screenshot menu is appearing under the menu button. I want the menu options to be displayed on clicking the menu button.